# How to you know if your script for Xcode CI server was executed?

Tags: xcode, bash, continuous-integration, xcode-server

I've made a custom script where I'm trying to move the .ipa file created from the build to my desktop.

Now when I run an integration I get no result from my script .
The vars.txt file isn't created on my filesystem and don't know how to verify that the script was actually executed .

Below is my simple script .

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "excuting the the file $0"

echo "SOURCE DIR = $XCS_SOURCE_DIR"
echo "OUTPUT DIR = $XCS_OUTPUT_DIR"
echo "PRODUCT DIR = $XCS_PRODUCT"

DESTINATION_PATH=~/Desktop

echo "SOURCE DIR = $XCS_SOURCE_DIR" > $DESTINATION_PATH/vars.txt
echo "OUTPUT DIR = $XCS_OUTPUT_DIR" >> $DESTINATION_PATH/vars.txt
echo "PRODUCT DIR = $XCS_PRODUCT" >> $DESTINATION_PATH/vars.txt
set >> $DESTINATION_PATH/vars.txt

echo "Starting to move file from $XCS_SOURCE_DIR to $DESTINATION_PATH"
cp $XCS_SOURCE_DIR $DESTINATION_PATH

FILENAME=(basename $XCS_SOURCE_DIR)
echo "Finished Copying file:$FILE_NAME to $DESTINATION_PATH"

echo "Moving into $DESTINATION_PATH"
cd $DESTINATION_PATH
```

Comment: are you able to manually echo into ~/Desktop/vars.txt ?

Comment: @RandomUser yes  ,  but as soon I run the script as a trigger I can't see any results

Comment: write "set -x" after #!/bin/bash in your script and run your script. Once done , please provide the output of execution.

Comment: `FILENAME=(basename $XCS_SOURCE_DIR)` will create an array containing `basename` and `$XCS_SOURCE_DIR`. You properly want `filename=$(...)`